# Is $A=\{z \in \mathbb{C}: |z^2-4|<1\}$ open and connected?

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, connectedness

**Definition** 1. An open set $A$ is connected if for every two points in A they can be joined by a path formed by segments of lines contained in $A$.

**Problem** Determine if $A=\{z \in \mathbb{C}: |z^2-4|<1\}$ is an open connected set.

After developing I have $A=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2}: x^4+2x^2+y^4+8y^2+15< 8x^2\}$, If a graph that set in $\mathbb{R^2}$ but if I graph in $\mathbb{R^3}$ is a surface but I can't see if $A$ is open or connected, or both. Could you help me?

Comment: Why do you say that $A\subset\Bbb R^3$? It is clearly a subset of $\Bbb R^2$, not of $\Bbb R^3$.

Comment: $A$ is disjoint from the imaginary axis, but contains $2$ and $-2$